# Better way to check if all values on dictionary are true?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dictionary

Ok, this is what i got:

```
var matchgrid = {
    "a1":[false, 0], "a2":[false, 0], "a3":[false, 0],
    "b1":[false, 0], "b2":[false, 0], "b3":[false, 0],
    "c1":[false, 0], "c2":[false, 0], "c3":[false, 0]};

var keys = Object.keys(matchgrid);

var ch = 0;

for (i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if (matchgrid[keys[i]][0] === false) {
            ch += 1;
        } else if (matchgrid[keys[i]][0] === true) {
            ch -= 1;
        }
    }

//then check it with:

if (ch === 9) {
    //do something
} else { 
    //do something else
}
```

as you can see, its a dictionary with arrays as values and i want to know if the first value of the all the keys is `false`, `true` or mixed, this works fine, but i'm sure that there's a better way to do it, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your native JavaScript approach is fine. Rather than storing the sum you may just store a boolean, start it as true, then if you see a false, set it to false. Then rather than check `ch == 9` just check for the boolean.

However, if you can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#every) (which has a lot of useful functions for lists), one of those functions is called [`every`](http://underscorejs.org/#every) that checks if every item passes the truth test. Then it becomes as simple as this

```
_.every(matchgrid, function(item) {
     return item[0];
})
```

Even shorter, and a little fancier:

```
_.every(matchgrid, _.first); // will return true if all elements are true
```

Comment: The problem with using a boolean is that it will take the last value stored as the result, i tried that before going with the sum as it will only be 9 if they're all false. i'll check underscore.js anyway.

Comment: Yeah if you want to check all true OR all false, you are better off using the sum. Checking just one is better using the boolean. Or you could use two booleans, one `allTrue` and another `allFalse`. The benefit of that is you can exit the loop early once you know what's up

Comment: +1 for breaking out of the loop if one is false without check all the rest of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ch = 0;

var result;
for (i=0;i<9;i++) {
        result = matchgrid[keys[i]][0];
        if (result) {
            break;
        } 
    }

// result will be false if they are all false
```